# Will inflating 25 views for a single item noticebly slow down scrolling in a ListView? (pls read details)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-recyclerview

I want to create a listview where displaying a single item would mean inflating at least 25 (exact number decided at runtime, reusing impossible) views such as TextViews and Linear Layouts. Will this noticeably slow down scrolling?

In other words,

Each item in  ListView is a complex object which consists of on average 25 LinearLayouts or TextViews (both) . As every object is different from the other they have different number of Views and they are differently organized. So I cannot reuse an item (cant use the view holder thing so). So it means I have to inflate and render 25 objects into screen for each item in the list.

Will scrolling run smoothly on an average phone?

Comment: do you want to know it will be slow or you  have implemented it and it is slow??

Comment: I didnt implement it yet, just needed to know if I should try some other way or if its ok to continue with this method.@VivekMishra

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are not loading heavy content in all of them you should be fine. Simple light weight views should not be an issue. I've populated 100s of views on a single layout and havent had any problem. (Note most of them were light weight.)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no problem at all. But if you are displaying images then it gets slow down. So for the displaying images use lazy loading.